# A top-level contract code file must have same name as application name GitexFeedbackZaheer specified in configuration file

Tags: azure-blockchain-workbench

I am creating Azure Block Chain Configurtion file and Contract when I upload the both to create the application I am getting below error

> Blockquote
>   A top-level contract code file must have same name as application name GitexFeedbackZaheer specified in configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple easy fix, You just need to Rename your *.sol file to have Application name you have mentioned in the *.json file

I.E.  You App name is MyFirstBlockChainApp then your *.sol file name should be MyFirstBlockChainApp.sol

> Blockquote
>   {
>     "ApplicationName": "MyFirstBlockChainApp",
>     "DisplayName": "My First Block Chain APP!",
>     "Description": " My Description here ",

[For More Information Check](https://scientistz.com/forums/topic/solved-a-top-level-contract-code-file-must-have-same-name-as-application-name-specified-in-configuration-file/)